# Revising ggplot after a function: non-numeric argument to binary operator error

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, dplyr

I am attempting to produce a ggplot from within a function. I can do so using the sample data and code below.

- If I produce the plot (p) outside of the function, I can revise it with no problem to add a title, subtitle, axis labels, etc. (e.g., `p + labs(title = "Most frequent words, by gender")`).
- However, if I produce the plot from within the function and then attempt to modify it, I get the following error: `non-numeric argument to binary operator.`
- In both cases, the object "p" shows up under Values.

I would of course like to use a function because I have a number of different group_by variables to test, and I want to eliminate typing mistakes (e.g., forgetting to change "gender" to "income" on a later analysis).

Can someone explain why the error arises only after modifying a ggplot created in a function? And of course I would be grateful for advice about how to eliminate the source of the error.

```
# sample data of favorite activities
df <- tibble(
  word = c("walk","hike","garden","garden","walk","hike", "garden","hike","hike","hike","walk"),
  gender = c("Male","Female","Female","Female","Male","Male","Male", "Male","Male","Female","Female")
)
df

# function to figure out the proportions of the activities
sum_text_prop <- function(df, groupbyvar) {
  groupbyvar <- enquo(groupbyvar)
  df %>% 
    count(!!groupbyvar, word, sort = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(groupbyvar = !!groupbyvar) %>% 
    mutate(proportion = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  top_n(proportion, n = 5) %>%
  ungroup()
}

# function to plot the most common words
plot_text_prop <- function(df) {
  p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = word, y = proportion, fill = groupbyvar)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.8, show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ groupbyvar, ncol = 2, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip()

  print(p)
}

# deploy the functions
df %>% 
  sum_text_prop(groupbyvar = gender) %>% 
  plot_text_prop()

# add a title to the plot
p + labs(title = "Most frequent words, by gender")

# error: Error in p + labs(title = "Most frequent words, by gender") : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

## Update

Thanks to the helpful responses, my revised code is as follows:

```
plot_text_prop <- function(df) {
  ggplot(data = df, aes(reorder_within(word, proportion, groupbyvar),
                         proportion, fill = groupbyvar)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.8, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~ groupbyvar, ncol = 2, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip()
}

p <- tidy_infl %>% 
  sum_text_prop(groupbyvar = gender) %>% 
  plot_text_prop()

p + labs(title = "Most frequent words, by gender")
```

Comment: Remove the `print` method in `plot_text_prop` function. You are not returning anything from it; And also `df %>% sum_text_prop(groupbyvar = gender) %>% plot_text_prop() -> p`.

Comment: Thanks! I had put the `print` there so I could see what it looks like before modifying it.

Comment: `p` is never defined in the global environment in the code you've posted.  I would guess it's not a `ggplot` object, which is why R thinks `+` should behave like numeric addition.